# Update the column which retain the old values using SAS SQL

Tags: sas, proc-sql

Need to update the column in the master file, say `Column1` has `A` & `B` values.

I have a different set of a file (mapping file) which has 2 different columns `Column1` has only `A` values & `Column2` has only `B` values which have unique values.

My requirement is to replace only `A` values to `B` and presented `B` values must retain same as in the column in the master file.

Please help me to write the update statement in SAS SQL.

I have tried this,

```
PROC SQL;
UPDATE MASTERTABLE K
SET COLUMN1 = (SELECT L.COLUMN2 FROM MAPPINGFILE L WHERE K.COLUMN1= L.COLUMN1);
QUIT;
```

Comment: For better understanding,attach a sample dataset of what your data looks like and how you want your output to be?

Comment: Your requirements are unclear.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to minimally track the master tables pre-map values as well as perform a mapping operation.  If this is not the case please edit the question with more detail and sample data.

The SQL `exists` operator will let you specify criteria that selects, for update, only those rows that need a mapping action.

```
data have_master;
  do row = 1 to 100;
    current_value = byte(65 + mod(row,26));
    prior_value = ' ';
    output;
  end;
run;

data have_map;
  length from_value to_value $1;
  input from_value to_value;
datalines;
A a
B d
Z K
run;


proc sql;
  update have_master
  set 
    prior_value = current_value
  , current_value = (select to_value from have_map where have_map.from_value = have_master.current_value)
  where
     exists (select * from have_map where have_map.from_value = have_master.current_value)
;

%let syslast=have_master;
```

I say *minimally track* because a subsequent use of the query can overwrite a `prior_value` assigned previously.